# Import JSON file in node application with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm really getting crazy because I can't find a solution for this.
What I want to archive is to import a JSON file with a configuration into my TypeScript file.
I've learned that I need a declaration file. So I've added a file json-loader.d.ts into my project. I also tried it at several levels (root, typings folder, custom_typings folder) because this are the solutions I've found.
The file content looks like this:

```js
declare module "json!*" {
    let json: any;
    export = json;
}

declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

But the compiler still tells me, that it is not possible to import the JSON file, because it isn't a module.
So, how is the compiler getting aware, that there is such a declaration file?

I already tried to modify my tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]  
}
```

But it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also show how you try to import the json?

Comment: I've tried: `import * as config from '../config.json'`. Should work when JSON is handled like a module I guess...

Comment: In case someone stumbles across that question. For nodejs applications you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-json-file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Examples on the web that use `declare module "*.json"` work because Webpack is configured to load JSON files.

If you don't want to bother with that you can use `var` instead of `import`:

`var json = require('../config.json');`

[as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952089/1709981)

Comment: Thanks. This works. Only forgot to run my gulp task that copied the .json file to the dist directory ... (ツ)

Comment: This gets me past the compile error but I still get a `Cannot find module` error at runtime. NOTE: Trying to import json into a jasmine spec file

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the following to import my `package.json` inside a CLI program (so I can re-use the version, license and description information in my help page).

```js
declare module '*.json' {
  const foo: {
    name: string;
    version: string;
    author: string;
    license: string;
    description: string;
  };
  export = foo;
}
```

Alternatively, you can import other files containing interface descriptions etc., but you need to put the imports *inside* the module declaration, e.g.

```js
declare module 'ormconfig.json' {
  import { Connection } from "typeorm";

  const foo: Connection[];
  export = foo;
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the above declare module bit, typings.d.ts?

Comment: @ArsalanKhalid As a separate file e.g. `ormconfig.d.ts` anywhere in your code should be fine... I normally add them to a utils folder or `typings` folder if I have many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done something like add a SystemJS script in your web page to do module loading - index.html etc. I used https://cdnjs.com/libraries/systemjs and iirc you need https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.14/system.src.js System.JS is the module loader.. Has to be first script imported.
And then you need something like this:

```
    <script
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.14/system.src.js "/>
    <script>
       System.config({
         defaultJSExtension:true
       });
      System.import('pathtoscriptwithoutdotjsatend');
   </script>
```

Comment: It's a node application. There is no web page. Should have mentioned it ... sorry.