# Read VSTS release variable at runtime (TypeScript/Webpack SPA)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm struggling to find a solution to what must be a fairly common problem passing a Visual Studio Team Services (*VSTS*) release variable into a Single Page Application (*SPA*) website. There are quite a few moving parts which I'll attempt to explain below.

I have created a release variable `ServiceLocations.ApiBaseUri` in VSTS that is unique for each environment (`dev/test/stage/prod`) and my end goal is for the value of this variable to be used by a typescript class (`~/src/services/ApiService.ts`).

- I can't do a text replacement as part of the webpack build because the build output is shared between environments.
- I can't inject into the build output because the contents of the `~/src/` dir is transpiled by webpack as part of the build into minified/uglified ES5 bundles with dynamic filenames.
- The website is hosted in a ASP.NET Core wrapper, running within IIS, otherwise I could leverage Node's filesystem library to read from a static file.
- I'm able to get VSTS to write the value into `appsettings.json` at the root of the project (outside `wwwroot`) but not sure how the SPA can read this at runtime.

Could anyone please offer any suggestions on a practical approach?

Comment: What's the problem to read json file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929021/import-json-file-in-node-application-with-typescript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use the replace tokens task? You can wildcard the filename. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Reading a JSON file at build time isn't the problem, we persist the same build output across multiple environments so the variable needs to be read/injected at time of release.

Comment: @DenverDev I did think about using a string replace at release time for the webpack output, e.g. `const apiRootUri = "#(APIROOTURI)#"`, but how would this work locally when developing?

Comment: You can set the value per to environment (1. Add the environments in your local machine and server machines 2. Set variable per to that environment value, for example: `let apiRootUri="develop test value"; if(!process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL){apiRootUri = "#(APIROOTURI)#"}`

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - thanks will try that!

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: I'll add the solution we came up with as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VSTS release process provides the ability to substitute variables into a JSON file as part of the IIS Site Deploy task.

[image: JSON variable substitution input field]

We are leveraging this to write the value of `ServiceLocations.ApiBaseUri` into a file (`~/clientconfig/settings.json`) which has the following initial contents allowing for local development:

```
{
  "ServiceLocations": {
    "ApiBaseUri": "https://localhost:44390"
  }
}
```

In the ASP.NET Core `Startup.cs` file, we are statically hosting this file so it is available by the SPA:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(
      Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "clientconfig")),
  RequestPath = "/clientconfig"
});
```

Then in the SPA's `ApiService.ts` we are using fetch to create a HTTP request for the settings file:

```
fetch("/clientconfig/settings.json", {
  method: "GET",
  credentials: "omit"
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(settings => {
  this._apiBaseUri = settings.ServiceLocations.ApiBaseUri;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create or edit the build in VSTS, besides the Tasks tab you also have a Variables tab. 
There you can setup your environment variables, including the base api url - that's what we do when we build a react app on VSTS (screenshot from a real build we have) [image]

Then in code you use it like this:
`export const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL;`
This is Javascript, but should be something similar for Typescript.

The only downside is that you will have to have separate build definitions per environments.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we are reusing the same build across multiple environments in order to maintain version parity. If we weren't I'd be able to utilise the VSTS variable in the webpack build.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the project using the `--environment="ENV_NAME"` where `ENV_NAME"` is the name of the environment you are targetting. 
(Note that it has to be registered in the `.angular-cli.json` config file under the node `environments`)

You can then define different values for the same variable in the various environment file. When building, Angular will use the values from the specified env file using the `--environment` flag.

To use the variable you will need to import it from the environment file doing

```
import { /*Your vars and/or functions */ } from "../../environments/environment";
```

**INDEPENDENTLY** from the environment you are targetting.

Comment: Thanks, I see where you're going with this however we aren't using Angular for the SPA. Is it possible to pick up an environment variable at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As your SPA is hosted in a ASP.NET Core wrapper I guess you could also retrieve your app setting `ApiBaseUri` in your `Layout.cshtml` file and create a global js variable with this value.

Let me know if you find some disavantages with this solution.