# What's the standard structure for a node module that contains JSON to make it easy for TypeScript users?

Tags: typescript, npm

Let's say I have a module in npm and I want users to be able to use it in there TypeScript projects. First, I'd make sure there was an `index.d.ts` in the package that way the compiler would understand my package for the user.

However, what if my npm module contains a JSON file? To get *my* module to compile with TypeScript, I'd add the following to my `typings.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

This allows *my* module to compile, but - based on my understanding - anybody else using my module would also need to include that in *their* `typings.d.ts` file.

As an example, if my module contained the following in an `index.ts`:

```
import * as _schema from './some-static-json-file.json'    

export function some_func(input: any): any[] {
    // do some stuff with _schema
    return []
}
```

And the user of my module did the following in their ts file:

```
import {some_func} from 'some-module'
```

their compiler would complain with a `Cannot find module './some-static-json-file.json'.`.

One solution is for the user to declare the same `"*.json"` module as I did in my `typings.d.ts` in their `typings.d.ts`. But it seems weird for me to require them to add that. They don't really care about the `some-static-json-file.json` file, they care about `some_func`.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Something isn't quite clear here. The JSON file already is an implementation detail, you don't have to do anything about it. The compiler error that you've shown is a different issue, because you cannot import JSON files with the import syntax. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32950966/1233251

Comment: You _can_ import JSON _if_ you declare a `*.json` module as I indicated (and as indicated in answers to the question you posted). The point of my question is that I don't want to force users of the module to have to declare the `*.json` too. Is there a way of structuring my module so they aren't forces to do that?