# How to reference a JSON file in TypeScript?

Tags: json, node.js, typescript, express, reference

I am currently trying to reference a JSON path and store it in a constant. I tried making a reference with a string and I res.send it as a response and it gave me back my string. So what would be the most adapted way to proceed to reference a JSON file in order to for example query fields of it?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Simply importing the file with nodejs will automatically convert it to an object. See the [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), specifically step 3 of `LOAD_AS_FILE(X)`.

Comment: I tried the LOAD_AS_FILE(X) but it actually doesn't let me store in a constant does it?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript compiler error when importing json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950966/typescript-compiler-error-when-importing-json-file)

Comment: It appears there was some confusion. `LOAD_AS_FILE(X)` is not an actual method but is technical writing describing how the module loading algo works in NodeJS. The point was to illuminate that JSON can be directly loaded in NodeJS without the need to manually read a file and parse the JSON to access the data represented by it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the contents of the JSON file loaded into the string already, you must just remember to set the `Content-Type` header on the response to `application/json`. This is what indicates to the client what the type of the response body is. Assuming you are using express, you just need to add `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` before your call to `res.send`.

Comment: Actually it seems like the content isn't loaded at all.. It just seems like a string containing my path. I just print the content of it or even res.json it it just returns me './keyfile.json'. Not the actual content of the JSON file. I am a bit lost in terms of syntax here. Seems like a hell just to reference a file and query its content...

Comment: I see... Sorry, I misread your question regarding the 'query fields of it' part... I believe that Jason Cust's answer should solve your issue then and hopefully mine will be of some use once you get the JSON loaded :)

Answer (score 0):

Within nodejs if a JSON file is simply imported then it will automatically be parsed into an object:

`const keyFile = require('./keyfile.json');`

**Update:** 
If you are using [TS >=2.9](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports):

> Support for well-typed JSON imports
>   TypeScript is now able to import JSON files as input files when using the node strategy for moduleResolution. This means you can use json files as part of their project, and they’ll be well-typed!
>
> ```
> // ./tsconfig.json
> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>         "module": "commonjs",
>         "resolveJsonModule": true,
>         "esModuleInterop": true
>         "outDir": "lib"
>     },
>     "include": ["src"]
> }
>
> // ./src/settings.json
> {
>     "dry": false,
>     "debug": false
> }
>
> // ./src/foo.ts
> import settings from "./settings.json";
> settings.debug === true;  // Okay
> settings.dry === 2;       // Error! Can't compare a `boolean` and `number`
> ```
>
> These JSON files will also carry over to your output directory so that things “just work” at runtime.

Comment: JSON file is not recognized as a module in TS as it indicates me in the error when I try the import. Can't I just simply reference a file in TypeScript and store it in a variable???!

Comment: @JulienHora I checked the docs directly and the answer is quoted directly from there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else who was confused like me: even with the new Typescript behavior, it still only imports the json file as a string, whereas if you use "require" it also converts the string to a JS object