# How do you import a JSON file with VueJS / Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I just created a clean VueJS new project and I can't get loading a JSON file to work.

#### Reproduction / Issue

For easy reproduction I've created a Github repo with my issue:
https://github.com/devedse/VueJSImportJsonFile

In the Home.vue page I'm trying to get Json loading to work. (https://github.com/devedse/VueJSImportJsonFile/blob/master/src/views/Home.vue)

When you open this solution in VSCode the following line shows an error:

```
import theJson from '@/assets/hi.json';
```

[image: Error in VSCode]
`Can't find module '@/assets/hi.json'`

When running NPM Serve the following error pops up:
[image]

#### What I've already tried

I've already searched all of stackoverflow and tried everything in the following posts:

[Importing json file in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript/50674344#50674344)

[Typescript compiler error when importing json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950966/typescript-compiler-error-when-importing-json-file)

https://github.com/chybie/ts-json

### Edit 1:

Ok I now managed to get it to work when running `npm run serve` by adding this to the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

However the error in VSCode seems to stay. Is there a way to fix this too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply add `resolveJsonModule": true` to your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`:

```
diff --git a/tsconfig.json b/tsconfig.json
index 499f5e2..a05dab1 100644
--- a/tsconfig.json
+++ b/tsconfig.json
@@ -6,6 +6,7 @@
     "jsx": "preserve",
     "importHelpers": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
+    "resolveJsonModule": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `tsconfig.app.json` config file add `"src/**/*.json"` in the list of patterns for the files to be included in compilation so it looks like this:

```
{
  "include": [
    "env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "src/**/*.json" <----- this
  ]
}
```

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include