# How to import json file in current vue default setup?

Tags: vue.js

There is this answer but it is wrong as it references tsconfig.json which is non-existant in vue projects now.

[How do you import a JSON file with VueJS / Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476994/how-do-you-import-a-json-file-with-vuejs-typescript)

I suspect the configuration option

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

should go somewhere. Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tsconfig.json is used when you use TypeScript.
If you used the Vue CLI to build your program, it should come with Webpack.
With webpack => 2.0.0, `json-loader` comes by default, so you can load .json files directly with

```
import jsonObject from '/path/to/file.json';
```