# Typescript always errors when importing a config.json file

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Code. 
VS Code is using Typescript v3.3.3.
I have installed the following packages via npm both locally (save-dev) and globally:

1. TestCafe v1.1.0
2. Core-JS v3.0.
3. TypeScript v3.4.1

I have also created a tsconfig.json file and added the property - "resolveJsonModule: true"

I have created a config.json file and it is being picked up correctly in my .ts file correctly after adding the resolveJsonModule property above -

```
Import config from './config.json';
```

However whenever I run my script I get the following error:

```
    Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
    /Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/UK/homepage-fixture.ts (2, 20): 
    Cannot find module './config.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' 
    to import module with '.json' extension at Function._reportErrors (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/te st-file/formats/typescript/compiler.js:45:15) at TypeScriptTestFileCompiler._reportErrors [as _precompileCode (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/typescript/compiler.js:79:40) at TypeScriptTestFileCompiler._precompileCode [as_compileCodeForTestFiles (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/te 
st-file/api-based.js:110:29) at TypeScriptTestFileCompiler._compileCodeForTestFiles [as precompile (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:169:21) at precompile (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:70:48) at Compiler._precompileFiles (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:66:54) at _precompileFiles (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/index.js:105:91) at map (/Users/test/Documents/Dev_Node/TestCafe/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/i ndex.js:105:41)
```

I've already tried the solutions provided here: [Typescript compiler error when importing json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950966/typescript-compiler-error-when-importing-json-file)

But none of them work for me.

Comment: "Consider using '--resolveJsonModule'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this longstanding issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1845 TestCafe uses its own TypeScript configuration, and doesn't honor any tsconfig.json that you use.

So it seems to me that your options are:

- Compile the TypeScript code yourself with your own tsconfig.json that includes the `resolveJsonModule` flag, and only let TestCafe see the resulting JavaScript code. TypeScript's `outDir` flag may be helpful here for copying the files to the right place.
- Create an interface (perhaps named `MyConfig`) describing the contents of your configuration, and import the JSON file with `let json: MyConfig = require('./config.json');` Not as good as letting TypeScript figure things out itself, but it should work around TestCafe's limitations.

Comment: Yes, I did look at that issue but wrongly assumed it had been fixed in Feb. I've tried to install the "require" npm package but I keep getting the following error during install `code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's typescript@3.3.3 does not satisfy typescript@^3.4.1` Looks like Testcafe's typescript is conflicting with the npm version?

Comment: Try to remove your `package-lock.json` and run `npm i -D testcafe typescript`.

Comment: Massive Massive Kudos to you Andrey!!

Comment: That has fixed my issue and I am able to use the config.json file using **require** - `var config = require('./config.json');`. I had to set the property _"moduleResolution": "node"_ in my tsconfig.json and run an npm command as the following TypeScript error was being thrown: `Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig`