# Import Array from JSON File into Typescript File

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I have a JSON file which contains an array object as such :

```
[
  {
    "VergiNo": "XXXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "VergiNo": "YYYYYY"
  },
  {
    "VergiNo": "ZZZZZZ"
  }
]
```

and I import this JSON file to my Typescript file

```js
import * as firmalar from "../firmalar.json";

const firmaPromises = firmalar.map((firma) => firma.VergiNo + "XYZ");
```

Above code gives no syntax error, however when I run the application and debug it, **firmalar** object is seen as object not an array, so it doesn't process map method.

Is there anything wrong that I'm doing here?

Comment: firmalar.json file return string just parse it with JSON.parse(firmalar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with using require() to get JSON and cast it to my object after that like this :

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const firmalar = require("./firmalar.json");

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
const firmalarArray: { VergiNo: string }[] = firmalar;
```

Now it works as expected. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952089/1189333) helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 9):

To import the JSON data, you should use:

```
import firmalar from "../firmalar.json";
```

This will import it without changing it, and you'll get an array.

When you did the import with `* as firmalar` it tries to convert the JSON into a module, which is a kind of Object. Inspecting it you'll see it has Object style accessors, so that `firmalar[0]` will work, but `firmalar.length` will not.

Comment: This works great! However you need to add the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flag to your `tsconfig.json` and set it to `true`

Answer (score 1):

I would try to parse the JSON. That should return you an array.

```
import * as firmalar from "../firmalar.json";

const firmalarArray = JSON.parse(firmalar);
const firmaPromises = firmalarArray.map((firma) => firma.VergiNo + "XYZ");
```

Comment: this gives a syntax error as firmalar isn't recognized as string. Even if I use : 

`const firmalarArray: [{ VergiNo: string }] = JSON.parse(firmalar.toString());`

it doesn't work in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You're importing a whole module.

You can either import only that constant:

```
import { yourArray } from "../firmalar.json";
```

Or extract the array from the module:

```
const firmalarArray = JSON.parse(firmalar.yourArray);
```